# how to use percentage to scale with ObjectAnimator android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Basically what I want is to scale a view either image or layoutrelative to a specific width according to its parent container. tanks

http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2015/02/05/150205092443820195.png

Comment: Find the width of the container and expand the Image?? Is this what you want

Comment: if I know the width and height of the parent, but what I need is how to scale the image to the full size of the parent using ObjectAnimator :).
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library:

- https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere

It have methods what you need.